# How to access help and support on Twitch.tv

Tags: twitch.tv

I want to ask some questions and to ask for help for fixing my problems with my account on Twitch.tv but on their website, there is no link whatsoever to anything like "Support" or "Feedback" or "Help".

And of course, I can't find any "Community" or "Forum" links, to ask this question there.

And then, how can I send a message to the staff at the Twitch.tv to ask them for help with my account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- help pages: **https://help.twitch.tv/**
- email support: **[https://help.twitch.tv/customer/e](https://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/emails/new?q=There...)**
- help support: **[https://help.twitch.tv/customer/frm](https://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/735178-partner-help-and-contact)**
- Twitter support: **https://twitter.com/TwitchSupport**
- Twitter Dev support: **https://twitter.com/TwitchDev**
- Discord support: **https://discord.gg/0gHwecaLRAzrRYWi**
- YouTube feed: **https://www.youtube.com/user/Twitch/feed**
- blog support: **https://blog.twitch.tv/**
- job support: **https://jobs.lever.co/twitch**
- IT support: **https://www.twitch.tv/p/security/**
- press suport: **https://www.twitch.tv/p/about/press-releases/**
- addvertising support: **https://twitchadvertising.tv/contact/**
- reddit comunity: **https://www.reddit.com/r/Twitch/**
- Prime support: **[https://help.twitch.tv/customer/prime](https://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/2572060-twitch-prime-guide#HelpContact)**
- developer forum: **https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/**
- developer support: **https://dev.twitch.tv/support/**
- phone / e-store support: **1-855-833-7774**
- legal support: **legal@twitch.tv**
- customer support: **help@twitch.tv**
- purchase support: **purchasesupport@twitch.tv**
- premium support: **turbosupport@twitch.tv**
- business support: **partnerhelp@twitch.tv**
- student support: **twitchstudent@twitch.tv**
- office address: **350 Bush Street, 2nd Floor, San Francisco, CA 94104 USA**
- CEO: Emmett Shear - **[@twitter](https://twitter.com/eshear?lang=en)**
- COO: Sara Clemens - **[@twitter](https://twitter.com/clemenssara?lang=en)**, **[@linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/in/saraclemens)**

Comment: Thanks, I don't have enough reputation so I can't vote for your answer yet. I really think they should add such links to their front page because such links are very important.